# Correct usage of Action and Events

Tags: c#, events

I am a bit new to `c#` so please overlook if you find it trivial. I saw the following "weird" code.

Can anybody shed a bit of light on it.

```
public event Action _action;

if (_action != null)            
{
    foreach (Action c in _action.GetInvocationList())
    {
         _action -= c;
    }
}
```

Specially the `_action -= c;` part.

Comment: Take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447821/how-do-i-unsubscribe-all-handlers-from-an-event-for-a-particular-class-in-c

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431359/event-action-vs-event-eventhandler for an overview of Action vs EventHandler

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A delegate can be a delegate to more than one function. If you have a delegate `alpha` that delegates to `Alpha()` and a delegate `beta` that delegates to `Beta()` then `gamma = alpha + beta;` is a delegate that calls `Alpha()` then `Beta()`.  `gamma - beta` produces a delegate that calls `Alpha()`.  It's a bit of a weird feature, to be perfectly frank.

The code you've posted is *bizarre*. It says "go through the list of functions in action, produce a whole pile of delegates that invoke fewer and fewer functions, and then finally assign a delegate that does nothing to `action`.  Why on earth would anyone do this? Just assign `null` to `action` and be done with it.

Answer (score 6):

```
public event Action _action; //an event


if (_action != null) // are there any subscribers?

{
        foreach (Action c in _action.GetInvocationList()) //get each subscriber
        {
            _action -= c; //remove its subscription to the event
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `public event Action _action;` is this bit ok? Meaning shouldnt Action take parameters from 1 to 16. Shouldnt it be like `public event Action<..> _action;`

Comment: If you need some kind of argument to the action, yes. But there are two versions of the Action class in the BCL. The non-generic you see here (Action) and the generic (Action<>). I'd however recommend to go with the standard event convention of using event EventHandler<>. See my comment on your question.

Answer (score 3):

It's removing the handlers for the action.

Comment: that's an unhelpful answer

Comment: @SamIam: Is it?  It is exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: @SamIam - yup - exactly what it does.

Comment: @SamIam: Really? OP can always follow up if clarification is required.

Comment: Just because it's true doesn't mean it's helpful.

Comment: Your answer is about as valuable as the answer `"yes"` in response to a question of the form `"is there a way to do x"`

Comment: @SamIam: Nope, it certainly is not.  A correct analogy would be answering "use named pipes" to the question "how do I communicate between processes in *nix?"  Terse, but correct. OP asked "what does this line of code do?".  This guy answered "it is detaching event handlers."  Terse, and also correct.

Comment: @SamIam I answered the question exactly as asked. That is the entire point of SO.

Comment: @msarchet  The point of SO is to help people fix their programming problems.  It's not trivia quiz meant for you to pad your epenis numbers.  In order to understand the answer you've given, someone would already have to know the answer in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

An event is actually a [`MultiCastDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx).  When you "attach" an event handler, it adds a reference to it's `InvocationList`.

The code above is detaching each event handler in the `InvocationList` from the event - essentially "clearing" the event, which could also be done by saying `_action = null`.