# How to remove all listeners from Firebase in C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my project I've got quite a nice amount of listeners set to listen for any changes in the realtime database. For some reason those listeners stay even if I reload the scene using

```
Application.LoadLevel("mainScene");
```

It would be quite a lot of hassle to remove each listener individually using

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
    .RootReference
    .Child("sub path 1")
    .Child("sub path 2")
    .ValueChanged -= SomeFunction;

FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
    .RootReference
    .Child("path")
    .ValueChanged -= AnotherFunction;
```

Is there a way to remove listeners from all paths?

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms the Firebase SDK has a call to remove all handlers from a location. But from a quick scan such a method doesn't seem to be available in the Unity SDK. If might be worth [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Note that even if such a method exists in C#, you'll still need to call it on each `DatabaseReference` your code uses.

Comment: C# has a way to do this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084469/how-to-remove-all-eventhandler .

Comment: Thanks Stewart! I'll close this as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: After a chat with Ben we can't do this from outside of the class unfortunately.  So it sounds like we'll need to add some way of ditching event handlers as part of the API.  We still need to figure this out unfortunately.

Comment: OK, I reopened the question. My original answer was correct then. :-)