# Firebase API questions (for Unity)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

While it is super cool to work with Firebase in Unity, it is quite a learning curve.

Two questions have come up that I think are both general and important in the way Firebase is used:

Can any Firebase developers enlighten these?

1. If you set a Firebase Query to null, will it also set all listener events attached to that query to null?
2. Can you always use -= to remove an eventhandler, EVEN if this is not set? Is there a way to check if a query already has an Eventhandler (like ValueChanged) attached?

Best regards

Ole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you set a Firebase Query to null, will it also set all listener events attached to that query to null?

No. You will need to explicitly remove the listeners as shown here: [How to remove all eventhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084469/how-to-remove-all-eventhandler)