# Remove all functions added to a Button.Clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

I was wondering if there is a way to remove all functions added to a Button.Clicked().

For example I have this button:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Clicked+=function_1;
btn.Clicked+=function_2;
btn.Clicked+=function_3;

void function_1(object sender,System.EventArgs e){
    //...
    //Same for function_2 and function_3
}
```

I need to remove all these functionalities from the button. I already know that I can do this:

```
btn.Clicked-=function_1;
btn.Clicked-=function_2;
btn.Clicked-=function_3;
```

But I am looking for a abstract way to do it. For example something like this (pseudocode):

```
foreach (f in btn.ClickedFuncions){
     btn.Clicked-=f;
}
```

Is it posible? How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try btn.Clicked= null; ?

Comment: @Serge Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. Button.Clicked only admits += or -= operators

Comment: no i didn't try this is why I am wondering. I know that events can be only  added or removed, but I am not sure about null. Look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084469/how-to-remove-all-eventhandler it has 24 upvotes. But as I uderstand it can work  from inside only