# How can I clear event subscriptions in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, events, c++-cli

I have a class Foo, which has a public event Bar. I need to clear all subscriptions to Bar.

In C# it is as easy as (within class Foo):

```
public void RemoveSubscribers() { this.Bar = null; }
```

(see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153573/how-can-i-clear-event-subscriptions-in-c) question)

How do I do this in C++/CLI? I cannot set Bar to nullptr: the compiler spits out the error

```
Usage requires 'Foo::Bar' to be a data member
```

I've had a look at the RemoveAll method of Bar, but I don't understand what I should supply as arguments...

EDIT 1:
For clarity, Bar was declared as follows:

```
public ref class Foo
{
public:
    event MyEventHandler^ Bar;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++/CLI hides underlying backing store (the delegate) even within the class so you can't simply set it to `nullptr`. Because you can't rely on default event implementation then you have to do it by yourself:

```
private: EventHandler^ _myEvent;

public: event EventHandler^ MyEvent 
{
    void add(EventHandler^ handler)
    {
        _myEvent += handler;
    }

    void remove(EventHandler^ handler) 
    {
        _myEvent -= handler;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply nullify `myEvent` delegate:

```
_myEvent = nullptr;
```

This, of course, will change how you'll invoke it too (same as C# instead of C++/CLI short version):

```
EventHandler^ myEvent = _myEvent;
if (myEvent != nullptr)
    myEvent(this, e);
```