# Make a c# / wpf event fire only once?

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

I have a case where I want a given event to execute once, and only once.  I'm trying to do it this way, but I'm having prolems (else I wouldn't be asking).  Note that the following code is inside the function that decides that the event needs to be fired.

```
EventHandler h = delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FiringControl.TheEvent -= h; // <-- Error, use of unassigned local variable "h"
  // Do stuff
}
FiringControl.TheEvent += h;
```

In general this should work because of the way scope is preserved for delegates until after they're done running, but, since `h` is in the process of being built when I try to use it it is still considered to be "uninitialized", apparently.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554845/am-i-using-the-right-approach-to-monitor-the-tasks-i-want-to-perform-when-a-handl/1554978#1554978

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set h = null first and then set it equal to something else?  Like this?

```
EventHandler h = null;

h = delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FiringControl.TheEvent -= h; // <-- Error, use of unassigned local variable "h"
  // Do stuff
}

FiringControl.TheEvent += h;
```

But are you sure this is the right approach?  What are you trying to do overall?

Comment: Yeah, that works perfect.  Had just figured it out and was coming back to delete the question, but I guess I won't now. ;)

Comment: As for what I'm doing, I'm temporarily hooking into `TheEvent` to potentially cancel another operation.  The "problem" is that there could be multiple of these happening at once, so I abuse local scope binding with delegates to avoid having to maintain a list of these.