# Solution to remove Event handler dynamically (using reflection). Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to remove event handlers from a control loaded from a dll that I don't have the code for. Since there doesn't seem to be an 'official' (i.e. supported by public methods of the .NET Framework), I was was able to create a couple extension methods that did exactly that using Reflection.

See this blog post for all the details: [Removing an Event from a WinForm ListView control using reflection](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/removing-event-from-winform-listview.html)

Here is a code sample of how to remove the SelectedIndexChanged event (dynamically and without access to the original handler)

```
//for a UserControl (in fact any control that implements System.ComponentModel.Component)
var userControl = new UserControl();
//we can get the current mapped event handlers
userControl.eventHandlers();
//its signature
userControl.eventHandlers_MethodSignatures();
//remove one by using the static field name
userControl.remove_EventHandler("EVENT_SELECTEDINDEXCHANGED");
//or use this one specifically mapped to the SelectedIndexChanged event
userControl.remove_Event_SelectedIndexChanged
```

My question is: "is there another way?"

Although my solution works and seems stable, I'm doing internal .NET objects manipulation, so maybe there is a better solution (in 4.0 or 4.5)?

Related posts:

- [How would that be possible to remove all event handlers of the Click event of a Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828054/how-would-that-be-possible-to-remove-all-event-handlers-of-the-click-event-of-a) - uses a similar solution to mine, but I don't think their solution works

Comment: If you don't know what the event handlers do, should you unbind them?

Comment: In this case I knew exactly what the event handlers where doing (and the fact that they were the root cause of an .NET exception that would happen on ListView item selection)

Answer (score 0):

can use folowing codes for remove events from controller , its a extention method :

```
    public static void EventHandlersClear(this Control control, params string[] eventKeyNames)
    {
        if (eventKeyNames == null) return;
        if (eventKeyNames.Length == 0) return;

        var allEventFields = typeof(Control).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var eventFields = allEventFields.Where(q => eventKeyNames.Contains(q.Name)).ToList();
        if (eventFields.Count == 0) return;

        var eventsProperty = control.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var events = (EventHandlerList)eventsProperty.GetValue(control, null);
        foreach (var eventKey in eventFields)
        {
            events.RemoveHandler(eventKey, events[eventKey]);
        }
    }
```

for example create a windows application with .net framework 4.8 :

[image]

behind code :

```
    private void ClearEventHandlersBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.EventHandlersClear("EventClick", "EventMouseDown", "EventMouseClick");
        button2.EventHandlersClear("EventClick", "EventMouseDown", "EventMouseClick");
        button3.EventHandlersClear("EventClick", "EventMouseDown", "EventMouseClick");
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button1_Click");
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button3_Click");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button2_Click");
    }
    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button1_MouseClick");
    }
    private void button2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button2_MouseClick");
    }
    private void button3_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button3_MouseClick");
    }
    private void button3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button3_MouseDown");
    }
    private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button3_MouseDown");
    }
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button3_MouseDown");
    }
```

**To use this extension method, you need to know the name of the events field in the control type.**

**Can use folowing code for get all event field names :**

```
typeof(Control).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```