# Remove Event Handler from BackKeyPress by Reflection

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to remove all handlers assigned to `BackKeyPress` event using reflection in Windows Phone application. I tried out many solutions, including [How would it be possible to remove all event handlers of the 'Click' event of a 'Button'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828054/how-would-it-be-possible-to-remove-all-event-handlers-of-the-click-event-of-a), but none of them worked in Windows Phone. Once I cannot use `EventHandlerList`, another time I get `System.FieldAccessException`. Has anyone run into the same or have a clue how can it be done?

Comment: I guess you don't want to do anything when user press on Hardwarebackbutton, Am I right..? or if not Can you explain your issue much more clear.

Comment: I assign new handler to BackKeyPress event in which I block back button (e.Cancel = true) and simultaneously I want to get rid of another handlers to avoid situation that any of them can cause closing app.

Comment: What do you mean that `I want to get rid of another handlers`

Comment: Normally you do object.BackKeyPress -= handler, but I do not have a access to "object" so my aim is to delete them by reflection, as far as I presume it is the only way out in this case.