# Remove a dynamically added event handler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have a code like:

```
button1.Click += (s, e) =>
{

};
```

Now how is it possible to remove this handler dynamically? something like:

```
button1.Click = null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point with events is that they are subscribe/unsubscribe, it is not the intention that you should unsubscribe other events then your own. Therefore you need to keep track of your event:

```
var click = (s, e) =>
{

};

button1.Click += click;
```

You can then unsubscribe it by:

```
button1.Click -= click;
```

**EDIT**

Seems you can use the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618521/3177092).

Comment: Is there any way to remove it without giving it a variable?

Comment: well I saw that approach and decided that its better to assign it to a variable ;)