# How to copy all event handlers one control to another at runtime in winui

Tags: c#, event-handling, handler, cloning, winui

I need to copy events of one control to another control.

In winui, Only have GetEvents() not GetHandlers(). How to achieve this.

Tried to clone a control. Copied all the properties using GetProproperties() method. But stuck in events.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283395/copy-all-event-handlers-from-one-control-to-another-at-runtime)?