# Intercepting and cancelling the Click event of a WinForms Button

Tags: c#, winforms, events, compact-framework

Is there a way to capture the Click event of a Button from the parent Control and prevent it occuring if a variable within the parent Control is true?

For example:

```
private void AssignEventOverrides()
{
    foreach (Button button in Buttons) 
    {
        // Get the event assigned at design time
        var someUnknownEventHandler = GetTheClickHandlerSomehow(button);

        // Unsubscribe the unknown event
        button.Click -= SomeUnknownEventHandler;

        // Assign the intercepting event
        button.Click += button_Click;
    }
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!preventClick)
    {
        // Fire the intercepted event that was previously unsubscribed
    }
}
```

Hopefully there's a nicer way to do this than the above example. Just to note, I don't have any control over the events assigned to the afforementioned buttons. They're subscribed elsewhere and I just need to prevent them happening if a variable is true on the consuming parent Control.

My real scenario:

I'm using Windows Mobile 6.5 (legacy application rewrite) I've created a panel control that can contain N number of child controls. The panel control allows for iPhone style vertical scrolling. I subscribe to the `MouseMove` event of the child `Control` and set a variable `_isScrolling` to `true`. In the `MouseUp` event I set `_isScrolling` to `false`.

As `Click` occurs before `MouseUp` I can check within the `Click` event to ensure a scroll hadn't occured when the button was pressed. So basically, if a scroll of my panel occurs, I need to prevent the Click event (subscribed at design time) from firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Hehewaffles answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860442/44269), here's the solution I came up with:

```
/// <summary>
/// Dictionary for holding the controls design time Click EventHandlers.
/// </summary>
private Dictionary<Control, EventHandler> _interceptedClickEventHandlers;

/// <summary>
/// Recursively moves through the child controls assigning events for scrolling and replacing Click events 
/// with an interception EventHandler that prevents the Click event occuring if the Panel was scrolled.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="control">The control to handle the events for and whose children to recurse through.</param>
private void RecursivelySubscribeChildEvents(Control control)
{
    if (!(control is IPanelItem))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Subscribe the events for the scroll handling
    control.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(UIPanel_MouseDown);
    control.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(UIPanel_MouseMove);
    control.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(UIPanel_MouseUp);

    // Intercept the click event
    FieldInfo eventClickField = typeof(Control).GetField("Click", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (eventClickField != null)
    {
        if (_interceptedClickEventHandlers == null)
        {
            _interceptedClickEventHandlers = new Dictionary<Control, EventHandler>();
        }

        // Get the original event and store it against the control for actioning later
        EventHandler eventClick = (EventHandler)eventClickField.GetValue(control);
        _interceptedClickEventHandlers.Add(control, eventClick);

        // Unsubscribe the old event and assign the interception event
        control.Click -= (EventHandler)eventClick;
        control.Click += new EventHandler(UIPanel_ChildClick);
    }

    // Recurse the event subscription operation
    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
    {
        RecursivelySubscribeChildEvents(child);
    }
}

private void UIPanel_ChildClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler interceptedHandler = _interceptedClickEventHandlers[(Control)sender];
    if (interceptedHandler != null)
    {
        // Fire the originally subscribed event if the panel is not scrolling
        if (!_isScrolling)
        {
            interceptedHandler(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might provide some useful insight

[How to remove all event handlers from a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control)

Specifically, look at

```
private void RemoveClickEvent(Button b)
{
    FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", 
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object obj = f1.GetValue(b);
    PropertyInfo pi = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events",  
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(b, null);
    list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
}
```

Comment: Should be `Click` instead of `EventClick` (on the CF anyway I think). I'll see if I can get this to work in my scenario.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction. This was very helpful, I'll post my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate way to look at the problem, why not just Subclass the hosting form and look for clicks on your targets.  If your `preventClick` is true, then mark the message as handled to prevent it from getting passed to the child.

Answer (score 0):

What about disabling buttons instead of setting variable within the parent Control to true?

UPDATE:
Setting `button.Enabled = false` definitely will prevent from Click event raising :)

UPDATE 2 (for real scenario): consider creating custom button

```
public class ScrollableButton : Button
{
    private bool _isScrolling;

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        _isScrolling = true;
        base.OnMouseMove(mevent);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
        _isScrolling = false;
    }

    public bool IsScrolling { get; set; }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isScrolling)
            base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Just replace default buttons with scrollable buttons.

Comment: An idea I'd already tried, unfortunately it doesn't work. I've fleshed out my question with the real scenario.