# Preventing default mouse behavior in C# - wpf

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, mouseevent

Is there an equivalent to Javascript's `event.preventDefault()` in C# (using wpf)?

I want to prevent the default behavior when left clicking anywhere in the screen.

```
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
    // I want to use something like Javascript's e.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: e.Handled = true ? You may want to do that on PreviewMouseDown event. You could also disable the top Parent, all children wouldn't respond to mouse events

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860306/intercepting-and-cancelling-the-click-event-of-a-winforms-button)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try `e.Handled = true` like so:

```
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
    e.Handled = true;
}
```