# How to remove all Event handler from a Control in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, events

I am using some recursive function during my form load. I am attaching event handlers on controls programmatically. Due to recursive function, event handlers get hooked multiple times to a control. I want to remove all handlers from these controls.

Eg. I have added keypress, keydown, gotfocus etc. events in a textbox. I want to remove all these handlers. How do achieve it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control

Comment: well it removes only the click event. I want to remove all the events from a control. How do I do it ?

Comment: It sounds like the multiple handlers was not intended... Wouldn't it be better to just keep from adding multiple handlers in the first place?

Comment: I want to add it once, not more than that. i.e. keypress, keydown, gotfocus all these once. but due to some function calls these are getting added more than once.

Comment: the method private void RemoveClickEvent(Button b) in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control does the job, but it only removes the click event.

Answer (score 1):

if `loEventHandler` is an event handler you've previously subscribed to an event (Click, for example), you can remove it by doing `loBox.Click -= loEventHandler;`.

Events can also be cleared within the private scope by setting the event to null `MyEvent = null;` That doesn't work for the public scope, though.

Comment: I am looking to remove all events. It can be messy if I add more handlers, more than 5,6. so I want to remove all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the "outside" world since events are special kinds of delegates which don't allow subscribers to interfere between each other.

Comment: the method private void RemoveClickEvent(Button b) in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control does the job, but it only removes the click event.

Comment: @NitinKabra: Well, that's kind of an hacky way to get the job done ;)

Comment: Ah. Hacky reflection. I suppose it works, just substitute the event you want to use for `Click`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a single event being registered multiple times , you can add a property wrapper like this

```
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> _event;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> PublicEvent
    {

        add
        {
            if (_event == null)
                _event += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            _event -= value;
        }
    }
```