# Unsign all event listeners, C# code example

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a C# class which introduce a new custom event type, and allows users add or remove listeners to it. Also I implement a method which revoves all event listeners during dispatch;

```
    public event EventHandler DataCommited;

    private void DetatchListeners()
    {
        if (DataCommited != null)
        {
            foreach (EventHandler eh in DataCommited.GetInvocationList())
            {
                DataCommited -= eh;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is possible to implement a method which will be taking DataCommited event as an argument. So, I can unsign a set of events using one method. I tried a lot ways implementing it, but unfortunately failed to do it. I wonder if it is actually possible and how. Thank you!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/91853/894872 will help you

Answer (score 2):

> It is possible to implement a method which will be taking DataCommited event as an argument.

Well, not really. You can take an `EventInfo`, but that's all. It's important to understand that this statement:

```
public event EventHandler DataCommited;
```

actually creates *two* things:

- An event, which code in other classes can subscribe to and unsubscribe from
- A field of type `EventHandler`, which you can use to call the handlers, or get each one individually.

A simpler implementation of your current code would simply be this:

```
public event EventHandler DataCommited;

private void DetatchListeners()
{
    DataCommitted = null;
}
```

Unsubscribing from a field-like event just changes the value of the field, after all.

However, if you have an `EventInfo`, you don't know how that event is implement. It *may* be backed directly by a field - it might not be... there's no general way of asking an event for its current handlers, or setting a new list of handlers. *All* you can do directly with an event is subscribe and unsubscribe.

*If* you only use field-like events, you could use reflection to find the name of the field and set the value to null. You can't do it in general though.

See my [article on delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it helps a lot. I'll go ahead and review the  article.