# Combox SelectedIndexChanged fires when close the WinForm

Tags: c#

I am using Combobox SelectedIndexChanged event to perform few tasks. It is working nice. But when i am closing the form, SelectedIndexChanged gets fired and i get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception. My code is following-

```
    private void cmbProductName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Product p =(Product) cmbProductName.SelectedItem;

            RawItems = RawItem.GetEntityList(p.Id, ConnectionString);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CustomMessageBox.ShowSystemException(ex);
        }
    }
```

How to avoid the SelectedIndexChanged event being fired when form is closing?

Thanks
SKPaul.

Comment: anything your setting related to cmbProductName in Form Closing event? or may be focus will be there in Combo.

Comment: firing Combobox SelectedIndexChanged  on closing not a normal behavior than be sure you not call it when closing

Comment: @Akerm- I am not calling it anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to perform the tasks only when user change selected item in combo box, it is better to implement the [`SelectionChangeCommitted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx) event

**[EDIT]**

According to MSDN docs `SelectionChangeCommitted` occurs only when the `ComboBox` selection changes by user (via keyboard or mouse) and it is not raised when the selection changes programmatically.

When a value is changed in the list, `SelectionChangeCommitted` event is fired first and then `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired.

So if we need to do anything on `SelectedIndexChanged`, we can remove it and do the same work in `SelectionChangeCommitted` event handler.

Simply handle this event instead of `SelectedIndexChanged` as below:

```
private void cmbProductName_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*
      Your event handling code
    */
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. But i have never use this event. I have to study it. But i would be grateful if you post a tiny example.

Comment: Thanks Khalifa. How can i satisfy you ? 10 out of 10 ?? ha haha. I am going to change my code.Thanks again.

Comment: SelectionChangeCommitted creating problems.

Answer (score 5):

Try unregistering the event in the FormClosing event handler:

MyComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= combox_SelectedIndexChanged;

Answer (score 2):

During the from closing you can remove ComboBox event handler. Therefore you need `Closing` event handler for your form and there you must remove `cmbProductName_SelectedIndexChanged` callback.

Here you can read about [Form.Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) and [how to remove event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control).