# How can i set a control event to null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events

H,

I have a listView with an event set to ItemChecked, now i need to do something like:

```
var tmp = this.listView.ItemChecked;
this.listView.ItemChecked = null; //set the event to null

// run some code which checkes some item in the list
// wehre the event shouldnt get fired on

this.listView.ItemChecked = tmp; //set the event again
```

Problem is that i can not read the event, i get the message that it can be used only on the left side of a statement.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can't you just unsubscribe all handlers, cache them in a local list, then re-subscribe them afterwards?

Comment: Check out the following answer [How to remove all event handlers from a control](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475424/519383).

Comment: @juan.facorro that only works if it's *your* event. See the accepted answer on that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.listView.ItemChecked -= myEventHandler;

// run some code

this.listView.ItemChecked += myEventHandler;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unsubscribe and resubscribe to do what you're trying to do:

```
private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.ItemChecked -= new ItemCheckedEventHandler(listView1_ItemChecked);

    // do stuff

    listView1.ItemChecked += new ItemCheckedEventHandler(listView1_ItemChecked);
}
```

Comment: What if the code is not able to assume that `listView1_ItemChecked` is the only subscribed handler?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that gets a lot harder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control

Comment: But that's what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove then add the event handler.  Assuming your code is in a method named ItemChecked

```
listView.ItemChecked -= ItemChecked;

// do whatever

listView.ItemChecked += ItemChecked;
```

However, I prefer checking for re-entrant calls.

```
object alreadyInItemChecked;

void ItemChecked(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Monitor.TryEnter(alreadyInItemChecked))
   {
      try
      {
          // do whatever
      }
      finally
      {
          Monitor.Exit(alreadyInItemChecked)
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe / unsubscribe to events as something like this.

```
        this.someObject.someObjectEvent += someEventHandler;
        this.someObject.someObjectEvent -= null;
```

So subscribe when you want the event to be fired and unsubscribe when not needed.