# The event can only appear on the left hand side of = or -=

Tags: c#-4.0

i have some problem in this code.. anyone help me

```
public event EventHandler CollectionChanged
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
            add
            {
                this.CollectionChanged = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(this.CollectionChanged, value);
            }
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
            remove
            {
                this.CollectionChanged = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove(this.CollectionChanged, value);
            }
        }
```

regards
sarva

Comment: What exactly is the issue do you want to remove the event delegation on remove ?

Comment: Umm... And what exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: The event CollectionChanged can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control

Comment: i need to use custom event (add and remove) with property changed... is there any better way in c#?