# How to recursively iterate through every object in a hierarchy and remove all event references?

Tags: c#, events, recursion, memory-leaks, event-handling

I need to remove all event bindings for every object in my system. There are thousands of objects that are holding events and this is causing memory leaks. I'm under a serious time constraint to get this sorted so I'm wondering if there's a way to recursively loop through an object hierarchy to remove the event bindings?

Comment: Winform? WPF? Asp.net? Silverlight? Shall I continue?

Comment: C#. Custom objects, custom events.

Comment: It seems that you have a big problem andhave to rewrite all classes in your system. Or drop your system off and write new one from the grounds.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with @KirillBestemyanov, in the process, also drop dinosaur winforms and use a contemporary XAML-based UI technology so that you don't have to deal with events anymore.

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control ?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This is all **really** hacky stuff, and I do not condone its usage!

That said...yeah, you can. Kinda.

Say you've got a class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
    public void Trigger()
    {
        if(SomeEvent != null)
        {
            SomeEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

We new one of these up, and connect to the event in a variety of ways:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.SomeEvent += FooEvent;
    }
    public void FooEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar.FooEvent!");
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar(foo);
foo.SomeEvent += (o,e) => Console.WriteLine("SomeEvent");

Console.WriteLine("Normal");
foo.Trigger();
```

Output:

```
Normal
Bar.FooEvent!
SomeEvent
```

All normal so far, right?

Now - the nastiness that is allowable via Reflection:

First, we'll need references to the `EventInfo` and the `remove` method for the event:

```
var theFooEvent = foo.GetType().GetEvent("SomeEvent");
var theFooRemover = theFooEvent.GetRemoveMethod(true);
```

Next, we'll abuse `Expressions` a bit to get the "present value":

```
var exp = 
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(foo), 
        "SomeEvent");
var member = exp.Member;
var rtMember = (member as FieldInfo).GetValue(foo) as EventHandler;
```

We're halfway there - now to blow away all the existing handlers:

```
var handlers = rtMember.GetInvocationList();
foreach(var handler in handlers)
{
    theFooRemover.Invoke(foo, new[] { handler });
}
```

There...that's it! Further calls to `Trigger` won't actually do anything:

```
Console.WriteLine("Post hackery");
foo.Trigger();
```

Output:

```
Post hackery
```

Answer (score 0):

Nasty.  It doesn't look possible with reflection unless you know the names of the event handlers; is it possible to modify the Dispose methods of your objects to remove their members' event handlers?

Comment: It might be, but that'll take a lot of code modification. I was hoping for a quick-n-easy approach. Unfortunately there might not be one of those!

Comment: It kind of surprises me that there isn't (or doesn't seem to be).