# remove all EventHandlers of a specific Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing an application in winForm. I have a panel in from1 and it has many event handler.
When I dispose panel1  and create new panel , the previous events exist & they  fire. For removing panel1 events I have tryed code below.

```
panel1.Click -=  clickHandle_1 ;
```

But it doesn't work every where in program code. for example in another method. 
How can I remove all previous events of panel1 when I create new panel1 ?

Comment: This is a code smell.  You could just write *one* event handler that does the job for all three.  Or simply derive a class from Panel that overrides the OnResize and OnClick methods.  Nor is it that clear why you'd want to remove them, a bool variable could be checked in the event handler to skip whatever it is doing.  Try to post meaningful code instead of this.

Comment: Agreed. I'd look into applying a variation of the strategy pattern here. http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event/91853#91853),
for cancelling all **Click Events** of panel1 do this:

```
FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.NonPublic);
object obj = f1.GetValue(panel1);
PropertyInfo pi = panel1.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(panel1, null);
list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
```

And for cancelling other events of panel1 change `EventClick` to event name that you want to remove.

One can get all event names using this code:

```
EventInfo[] info = type.GetEvents();
for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(info[i].Name + "\n");
}
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting `discovery` on the `static private fields`, you might have to search much?

Comment: you should have put source of the original answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/91853/2377343

Answer (score 4):

Normally when you `Dispose` an object/control, all the members of that object/control including `Event handler list` should be disposed too and **unusable**. So when you say `your panel1 is disposed`, it's impossible to fire any event on that disposed control (such as `Resize`). **You should check if you surely dispose your panel**. Here is a way you can use to remove all the `Event handlers` of a control using `Reflection` to `Dispose` the `Events` (type of `EventHandlerList`):

```
public void RemoveHandlerList(Control c){
  EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList) typeof(Control).GetProperty("Events", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(c, null);
  typeof(EventHandlerList).GetMethod("Dispose").Invoke(list, null);
}
```

Comment: not impossible ! I mean when i dispose panel1 & create new instace of it , when i resize panel , the previous events invoke !! you can test!

Comment: @AmirHosseinRezaei could you post the code showing how you `Dispose` your panel?

Answer (score 3):

Remove them one at a time:

```
panel1.Click -= clickHandle_1;
```

There is no clean way of unsubscribing all event handlers at once. Keep track of what you're subscribing and unsubscribe them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but this is closest I came with:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private Dictionary<string, EventHandler> _handlers = new Dictionary<string, EventHandler>();
    TextBox _txt = new TextBox();

    void WireHandlers()
    {

         // get references of your handlers
         EventHandler _hnd1 = delegate { return; }; // here will be your named method. This is only for example
         EventHandler _hnd2 = delegate { return; }; // here will be your named method. This is only for example

         // wire handlers
        _txt.Click += _hnd1;
        _txt.TextChanged  += _hnd2;
         // save wired handler collection
        _handlers.Add("Click", _hnd1);
        _handlers.Add("TextChanged", _hnd2);
    }


    void UnwireHandlers()
    {

        // lets unwire all handlers
        foreach (var kvp in _handlers)
        {
            // inspect keyValuePair - each key corresponds to the name of some event
            switch (kvp.Key)
            {
                case "Click":
                    _txt.Click -= kvp.Value;
                    break;
                case "TextChanged":
                    _txt.TextChanged  -= kvp.Value;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("no such handler found");
            }
        }

        _handlers.Clear();
    }

}
```