# How to remove delegate from EventHandler in Xamarin UWP?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to remove a `Delegate` from an EventHandler`in`Xamarin.UWP`. Specifically I am trying to implement a` CustomRenderer`for the Xamarin.Forms`Entry`, and I would like to remove an event handler delegate that has been assigned to the` KeyUp EventHandler`for`FormsTextBox` in Xamarin.

I have tried using the info found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660480/determine-list-of-event-handlers-bound-to-event) but it seems that does not work in Xamarin. Any thoughts on how I a can achieve this?

I have something like this in my `OnElementChanged` override for my `CustomRenderer`.

```
 FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("KeyUp",
   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            
object obj = f1.GetValue(this.Control);
            
PropertyInfo pi = this.Control.GetType().GetProperty("Events",  
  BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(this.Control, null);
list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
```

the value of `f1` always return null not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I also tried using the info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773844/remove-all-eventhandlers-of-a-specific-control) to find the right event name (which I determined to be `KeyUp`), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Null means that the control doesn't have a such field. Normally, get the keyup event with the code `EventInfo f1 = typeof(MainPage).GetEvent("KeyUp",
  BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);`

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work like this.

```
var keyUpRuntimeEvent = this.Control.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent("KeyUp");

Action<EventRegistrationToken> removeEventHandlerAction =
    (Action<EventRegistrationToken>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<EventRegistrationToken>),
        this.Control,
        keyUpRuntimeEvent.RemoveMethod);

WindowsRuntimeMarshal.RemoveAllEventHandlers(removeEventHandlerAction);
this.Control.KeyUp += TextBoxOnKeyUp;
```