# How to remove all event handlers from a control in VB.NET

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

I found this very interessting Code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control).  I tried to translate it to VB.NET, but I am not able to. I want to remove all Handlers for the event 'click' of a known button.

Can anybody help me and translate it to VB.NET?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        button1.Click += button1_Click2;
        button2.Click += button2_Click;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }

    private void button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("World");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveClickEvent(button1);
    }

    private void RemoveClickEvent(Button b)
    {
        FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", 
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        object obj = f1.GetValue(b);
        PropertyInfo pi = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events",  
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(b, null);
        list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct translation into VB syntax, as per the OPs request.

```
Imports System.Reflection    ' Required if not already in your code
Imports System.ComponentModel

Partial Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        AddHandler button1.Click, AddressOf button1_Click
        AddHandler button1.Click, AddressOf button1_Click2
        AddHandler button2.Click, AddressOf button2_Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    End Sub

    Private Sub button1_Click2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("World")
    End Sub

    Private Sub button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        RemoveClickEvent(button1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveClickEvent(b As Button)
        Dim f1 As FieldInfo = GetType(Control).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Dim obj As Object = f1.GetValue(b)
        Dim pi As PropertyInfo = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        Dim list As EventHandlerList = DirectCast(pi.GetValue(b, Nothing), EventHandlerList)
        list.RemoveHandler(obj, list(obj))
    End Sub
End Class
```

It works fine, provided of course the form has `button1` and `button2` dropped onto it.
The thing that makes people reject your question (aside from @phaedra 's perfectly valid comments) is that there is little point in this code.  The function `RemoveHandler` can be used instead.