# CheckedListBox prevent click event from firing if only the checkbox was clicked?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

How can I prevent the click event from firing, if the click was on a checkbox?

I mean, when I click in the text area, I'd like to handle that but when the checkbox is being clicked, I don't want that click code to fire.

Comment: either remove the event handler code for that particular event or code your own pre / post action checks do you have existing code to show what you have and the issues you are currently facing...?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the delegate from the delegate list [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control)

Alternativement (and probably more safely) you can simply wrap the on click event in a if and prevent the code from executing under some circumstances.