# How to supress the F1 functionality in SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog, chm

I want to prevent the opening of help (.chm) when the F1 key is pressed in the SaveFileDialog. 
I actualy have another chm used in the application Windows but when clicking the SaveFileDialog an extra chm of Microsoft is opened which i do not want.

Comment: Can you assign the HelpProvider on the dialog?

Comment: What operating system and development environment you are using? Is focus on the form or on the save button of the SaveFileDialog? I tried on my Windows 10 machine with Visual Studio 2015 installed and I get a Windows 10 internet help site without doing some special help call at this stage.

Comment: OS: win7.
dev. env.: vs2013.
I do not want the windows help rather to use my own chm which works in other forms of the application (or even to prevent any help).

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`ShowHelp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.showhelp(v=vs.110).aspx) to false or handle the [`HelpRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.commondialog.helprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) event. You could show your own help there if you want to.

Comment: The ShowHelp = false. did not done the job. Also i tried to remove the events of HelpRequest by using code i found in http://stackoverflow.com/a/91853/4948887 is that what you ment? (it did not done the job as well )

Answer (score 0):

just make a new event for the opened Window and check if F1 is klickt. if yes open your help info thing.

Comment: I think it wont help. I can't create new event for the standart SaveFileDialog and even if it is posible with extention method it wont prevent the microsoft help from showing. Do someone have any solution for this question? Nothing from the above helped