# PropertyInfo button.GetProperty events return null

Tags: c#, propertyinfo, getproperty

I'm trying to get button eventclick with reflexion. I would like to get "Btn_AddTest_Click" string for assign it to a CommandBinding.
For example:

XAML

```
<Button x:Name="Btn_Add"
    Click="Btn_AddTest_Click"/>
```

Behind

```
public async void Btn_AddTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{...}
```

And function:

```
Type ObjType = Btn_Add.GetType();
PropertyInfo eventsProperty = ObjType.GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

EventHandlerList events = (EventHandlerList)eventsProperty.GetValue(Btn_Add, null);
```

But  "eventsProperty" return Null, i tried with "Events", "EventClick", Click"... same return.

I got inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control)

Comment: EDIT:        private async void Btn_AddTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {...}

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to look at the RoutedEvents for the button. This will get you the `Click` routed event:

```
        var eventStore = Btn_Add
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty("EventHandlersStore", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .GetValue(Btn_Add, null);

        var clickEvent = ((RoutedEventHandlerInfo[])eventStore
            .GetType()
            .GetMethod("GetRoutedEventHandlers", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Invoke(eventStore, new object[] { Button.ClickEvent }))
            .First();
```

And to invoke it:

```
clickEvent.Handler.DynamicInvoke(null, null);
```

Comment: thank you so much, i find 'Btn_AddTest_Click' in "clickEvent.Handler.Method.Name;" but i can't convert this to ExecutedRoutedEventHandler for CommandBinding NewCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(NewCommand, Btn_AddTest_Click);

Comment: Was not the same subject, I asked my second question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760585/how-get-commandbinding-executed-from-routedeventhandlerinfo  Thank again Lockdowne