# c# remove all event handler from BackgroundWorker.DoWork by Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, backgroundworker, eventhandler

i am helped by this link -[How to remove all event handlers from a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control)

yep i succeed remove all event handler from control and form.

but i have failed in BackgroundWorker.

this is my code.

```
    void ReadingCompleted()
    {
        //find fields
        List<FieldInfo> liField=typeof(BackgroundWorker).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public).ToList();

        foreach(FieldInfo field in liField)
        {
            txtbox_log.Text += field.Name + "\r\n";
        }
        //below output list 
        //canCancelWorker
        //workerReportsProgress
        //cancellationPending
        //isRunning
        //asyncOperation
        //threadStart
        //operationCompleted
        //progressReporter
        //doWorkKey
        //runWorkerCompletedKey
        //progressChangedKey

        //remove all eventhandler
        object key = typeof(BackgroundWorker).GetField("doWorkKey", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        EventHandlerList events = (EventHandlerList)typeof(Component)
        .GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(this, null);
        events.RemoveHandler(key, events[key]);
        waitForm.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *strongly* recommend against writing code like this. A well-designed implementation should have no need to arbitrarily remove all handlers subscribed to any event of any class, including the `DoWork` or other event of `BackgroundWorker`. The only code that ought to be removing a handler is the same code that added the handler, and that code *knows* what handler it added and so can remove it directly.

That said, assuming the code you posted is found in a class that inherits the `BackgroundWorker` class, the only reason it doesn't work for you is that you are trying to use the `FieldInfo` object you get back from the `GetField("doWorkKey", ...)` call as the actual key for the event handler, which in fact you should be calling that object's `GetValue()` method to get the actual key value.

The correct code would look like this:

```
FieldInfo keyField = typeof(BackgroundWorker)
    .GetField("doWorkKey", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
object key = keyField.GetValue(bw);
```

If the code you posted is *not* in a class that inherits the `BackgroundWorker` class (or, even if it is but it's not the `BackgroundWorker` object you are trying to modify), then you have a second problem. You also need to provide the correct `BackgroundWorker` instance when calling the `GetValue()` method here:

```
EventHandlerList events = (EventHandlerList)typeof(Component)
    .GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(this, null);
```

That is, instead of passing `this` to the `GetValue()` method, you would need to pass the reference to the actual `BackgroundWorker` object you're trying to modify.