# C# how to unsubscribe all event handlers of a control (RadioButton)

Tags: c#, radio-button, controls, eventhandler, unsubscribe

I have a GUI that contains 10 radio buttons and a textbox, into which the user has to make his input. The RadioButton.CheckedChanged event gets subscribed on runtime depending on the user input (textbox). So, in my case there over 50 possible methods that can subscribe to the CheckedChanged event. Ok, I can unsubscribe every single method one by one (see excerpt from my code), but isn't there are any less time consuming and more efficent way to do this? Something like for instance:
unsubscribe all methods from the CheckedChanged event at once. Or: determine the method that currently subscribes to this event und unsubscribe this method.
I was already searching for an existing solution and found this: [How to remove all event handlers from an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event) but in my case this solution does not works. As I mentioned, in my case there radio buttons, not normal buttons.
Excerpt from my code:

```
 public List<RadioButton> RbList
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        RbList = new List<RadioButton>
        {
            radioButton1, radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4, radioButton5, radioButton6, radioButton7,
            radioButton8, radioButton9, radioButton10
        };

    }
    private void Unsubscribe()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < RbList.Count; i++)
        {
            RbList.ElementAt(i).CheckedChanged -= Method1;
            RbList.ElementAt(i).CheckedChanged -= Method2;
            ...
        }
    }
```

Additional information regarding to the asked questions:
The last subscribed method does not get unsubscribed. With the radio buttons specific PDFs gets called. In the background is still the last subscribed method as long as another method is not get subscribed. So, if the user change the input in the textbox and the input does not matched anymore so that any other method can't be subscribed, the last method ist still there and the with the method associated PDFs can be accessed and that's exactly what I want to stop. I wouldn't have the problem, if the PDFs could by only accessed by clicking on the radio button. Then I could simply make all the radio buttons unvisible/unaccessible. But this is not the case, there is another option to the user to call the PDFs, which I dont mentioned - additionally there is a second textbox and if the input in this textbox is equal to the RadioButton.text the associated radio button gets also checked and the associated PDF to this radio button gets called and this is where the problem starts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all event handlers from an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event)

Comment: Can you describe *how* the solution from the linked question "does not work"?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you just had logic in a single event handler that called the appropriate method based on the user input, rather than trying to manage event subscriptions.

Comment: I added additional information to the description.