# How to correctly override System.Timers.Timer Elapsed Event

Tags: c#, events, system.timers.timer

I want to override the default Elapsed event for the System.Timers.Timer class to easily be able to remove all event listeners when desired. Using Jorge's answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event) question, I came up with the following

```
       class CustomTimer : System.Timers.Timer {

            List<ElapsedEventHandler> delegates = new List<ElapsedEventHandler>();

            private new event ElapsedEventHandler _elapsed;

            public new event ElapsedEventHandler Elapsed {
                add {
                    _elapsed += value;
                    delegates.Add(value);
                }
                remove {
                    _elapsed -= value;
                    delegates.Remove(value);
                }
            }

            public void RemoveAllEvents() {
                foreach (ElapsedEventHandler e in delegates) {
                    _elapsed -= e;
                }
                delegates.Clear();
            }
        }
```

When I run the service that this is executing in, I can trace through to see that the private Elapsed member is being assigned. However I'm not able to see the event handler actually execute. Did I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i did it :

```
public void AddElapsed(ElapsedEventHandler newHandler)
{
    base.Elapsed += newHandler;
    delegates.Add(newHandler);
}
```

Then only use `AddElapsed()` instead of `Elapsed +=`

Maybe add the following as well:

```
[Obsolete]
public new event ElapsedEventHandler Elapsed;
```

Comment: Did you still have to define a public event and private backing?

Comment: @pingOfDoom i don't touch the event, just inherited from timer and added a new method.

Comment: You don't have to redefine the event in the derived class?

Comment: nope you don't have to. If you want you can i guess and throw a warning that the new method should be used. Or maybe add an `[Obsolete]` attribute to the elapsed event