# remove firebase observer from database node in unity c#?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, observers

I got this firebase observer in my playersRef child node as:

```
playersRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("players");
playersRef.OrderByChild("level") .ValueChanged += (object sender2, ValueChangedEventArgs e2) => {}
```

Now, when my game object is destroyed.
I want to remove this observer at playerRef which is called on some value changes.

PROBLEM:
I cannot find any way to silence this observer. Like in other languages , firebase allows us to removeAllObservers() like as :

```
 ref.removeAllObservers()
```

But , in unity C# searching through firebase doc, I see no option to remove observers.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/database-reference

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answer lies in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data), you can unsubscribe from the event by using (-) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the previous answer. You'll want to do the following:

1) Actually name the function to handle the event (so you can `-=` it later):

```
private void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
}
```

2) Cache the reference to the Query that you'll be using ValueChanged with:

```
Query _cachedQuery;

void Start() {
    playersRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("players");
    _cachedQuery = playersRef.OrderByChild("level");
    _cachedQuery.ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
}
```

3) When you're done, remove the listener. For bonus points, check if it's non null (ie: if you do use Start instead of Awake, this will handle the case that the object had `DestroyImmediate` called on it before the first update loop).

```
void OnDestroy() {
    if (_cachedQuery != null) {
        _cachedQuery -= HandleValueChanged;
        _cachedQuery = null;
    }
}
```

C# itself generally does not allow you to "RemoveAll" from an event (you can [work around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event) though). But if you're used to that pattern or (like me) prefer to work in `UnityEvent`s, you can always do all of this in a class that exposes a `UnityEvent`. Then you can call [RemoveAllListeners](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEventBase.RemoveAllListeners.html) on this proxy class you create (although I would consider `RemoveAll` a "code smell" in my own personal style, it's up to each team to decide what they do and don't consider good code).