# C# How to clear handlers from custom events

Tags: c#, events, reflection, delegates

I have a `UserControl`, named `FormDesignerControl`. `FormDesignerControl` has a number of public events on it, declared thus:

```
public event EventHandler LeftMouseClick;
public event EventHandler LeftMouseDownInControl;
public event EventHandler LeftMouseMoveInControl;
public event EventHandler LeftMouseUpInControl;

public event EventHandler LeftMouseDownInThumb;
public event EventHandler LeftMouseMoveInThumb;
public event EventHandler LeftMouseUpInThumb;

public event EventHandler RightMouseClick;
public event EventHandler RightMouseDownInControl;
public event EventHandler RightMouseMoveInControl;
public event EventHandler RightMouseUpInControl;
```

At one point, I pass an instance of `FormDesignerControl` from one place in my program to another and want to all the handlers. I do not have access to the original events. Basically, I need to clear the current settings of the event handlers. Ideally what I'd like to do is this:

```
FormDesignerControl oFDC = new FormDesignerControl();

// some code occurs manipulating oFDC and setting the events on it, and then at some point...

oFDC.LeftMouseClick.Clear(); // but this isn't facilitated
oFDC.LeftMouseClick += myNewEventCode;
```

It seems the only way to do this is to have access to the original events so as to be able to use the `-=` operator.

Is there a way to clear an arbitrary event from an arbitrary object, perhaps using `System.Reflection` even if I have to encapsulate it in a method? Something like this:

```
void ClearEvent(object obj, string eventName)
```

Comment: Already answered on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event

Comment: The code there doesn't appear to work with any event for any object, only Button clicks on form controls. I've tried using it and it errors. I have found a generic solution, though, here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103542/Removing-Event-Handlers-using-Reflection which appears to work irrespective of class or event.

Answer (score 0):

Generic (and very neat, I might say) solution to remove any event handler from any object found. Single line solution here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103542/Removing-Event-Handlers-using-Reflection

```
EventHanderHelper.RemoveEventHandler(oFDC, "LeftMouseClick");
```