# How to remove all registered event handlers of a specific event from a UWP Control

Tags: reflection, uwp

I would like to know, how can I remove all the event handler registered in a particular event in a UWP Control (e.g., button or toggle switch). Consider the fact that I don't have any access to the event handle, so I can't use the deregister method like "some_event -= my_event_handler".

I found some solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event] in stack overflow for the similar problem using reflection; however the solutions didn't work when I tried to implement the for UWP controls.

Comment: Have you checked my reply about removing the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

In UWP document [Removing event handlers in code.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#removing-event-handlers-in-code)

> It's not usually necessary to remove event handlers in code, even if
> you added them in code. The object lifetime behavior for most Windows
> Runtime objects such as pages and controls will destroy the objects
> when they are disconnected from the main Window and its visual tree,
> and any delegate references are destroyed too.

If you need to remove the event handler, you can only use `-=` and [UIElement.RemoveHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.removehandler?view=winrt-22621), both methods require an event handler.