# Adding events with parameters but need to remove them again

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, parameter-passing

So in a form I am dynamically creating objects and passing extra values, this works using the code below. I cannot find a way of removing the click event that actually works. Anyone know how to without deleting and recreating new objects

Adding behaviour to the control:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button) && c.Name.Length == 7)
    {
        c.Enabled = true;

        //add the event handler, passing the optional string in, reading the letter from the name
        c.Click += (sender2, e2) => ButtonClick(sender2, e2, c.Name.Substring(c.Name.Length - 1, 1));
    }
}
```

Trying to remove using this code:

```
c.Click -= ButtonClick;
```

I have also looked at trying to use event handler objects to remove it but cant get it to work.

I have had success with removing events when I dont pass a parameter to the method but then that causes other problems.

Would appreciate if anyone knows how to remove the event as I have added it above.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't add `ButtonClick` in the first place so you can't remove `ButtonClick`. What you added was a lambda that calls `ButtonClick`, so that's what you need to remove. If you need to add and remove, why not use a named method instead of a lambda in the first place?

Comment: couldnt get a named method to work with a parameter. This was the line of code that worked

Comment: Found a solution here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event )

Comment: If you couldn't get a named function to work it's because you made the same mistake of confusing the event handler with a method called by the event handler. In the code you posted, your event handler only has two parameters, as normal. That event handler then calls a method with three parameters. You can do that with a named method just the same as you can with a lambda. What do you not understand about calling one method from another?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). Local functions are methods that are nested in another method. They can only be called from their containing method. For example the `Button_Click` below is a local function:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    void Button_Click(object sender2, EventArgs e2)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender2;
        button.Click -= Button_Click; // Remove the handler
        string suffix = button.Name.Substring(button.Name.Length - 1, 1);
        DoSomething(button, suffix);
    }

    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        if (c is Button && c.Name.Length == 7)
        {
            c.Click += Button_Click;
            c.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by using the method shown here [remove all event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event)

```
private void RemoveClickEvent(Button b)
    {
        FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", 
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        object obj = f1.GetValue(b);
        PropertyInfo pi = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events",  
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(b, null);
        list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
    }
```